# How to register user app to get notified with battery events(low, critical etc.) in Yocto?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, yocto, battery

I am writing power supply driver`(mypower_driver.c)` which registers two power supply and implements couple of power supply properties like `status`, `present`, `capacity` etc.

1. Battery
2. AC(Mains)

I am using `Yocto warrior` branch and `4.19.62-intel-pk-standard` Linux kernel for my device which is headless(No display).

I know power supply class exposes `sysfs` attributes but my objective is to get notifications when there are any battery attributes changed.

Can I register my user application(test.c) with battery subsystem and get notified or some function callback when any events occurs(low or critical battery) on power supply devices(AC and battery in my case)?

Do I need to do anything in power supply driver`(mypower_driver.c)` to pass information(such as low or critical battery ) to the Linux battery management subsystem?

Thanks for you time and any lead on this will be really helpful.

Comment: Look into source code of GNOME or other UI utilities on real desktops. I believe the ABIs are also described in the documentation (kernel).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I couldn't find much relevant info and GNOME source code seems to be so huge to dig in. Can you point me some specific documentation or something?

Comment: Sorry, I have no time to dig myself. And honestly I don't need that information :-)